# How to identify actual file updated vs item properties update in the SharePoint item updated event

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way we can identify in the item updated event that the document(File) associated with the item is updated or not?

Thanks,
Mallikarjun

Comment: I am not sure it is completly clear what you want. I guess you have a class inheriting from `SPItemEventReceiver` and have overwritte it's `ItemUpdated` method. And you wan't to find out whether the file itself has been overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

how about comparing Created Date and Updated Date fields if same or not?

or you can compare with last version;

SPListItemVersionCollection oVersionInfo = oListItem.Versions;

Comment: if we update only metadata and not file, then also both are different

Comment: @RajuJoshi you mean files metadata? or ListItem's column?

Comment: how about comparing with last version? I edited my answer

Comment: if we update the metadata fields of list item, updated date is changed so we cant use that

Comment: not SPListItems date, the files. you can compare files byte lenght or file last changed date.